# I get a webpack warning Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression when use koa

Tags: webpack, koa

When I start webpack for bundling my react application using koa with server side rendering I get a warning

```
WARNING in /app/node_modules/any-promise/register.js 24:14-37
[1] Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
[1]  @ /app/node_modules/any-promise/index.js
[1]  @ /app/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js
[1]  @ /app/node_modules/koa-convert/index.js
[1]  @ /app/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js
[1]  @ ./server/index.ts
```

Should I worry?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I answered this question a few hours ago in `any-promise` Github repository.

So I just copy the answer here:

It happened because `register.js` has a dynamic import on 24 lines:

```
var lib = require(implementation)
```

It means webpack can't resolve the require statically and imports entire package

You can read this part of webpack docs: https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression

It can be solved using `ContextReplacementPlugin`, for example, you can add "fake" config in your webpack to suppress this warning

```
plugins: [
    new ContextReplacementPlugin(/any-promise/)
]
```

And I think you don't have to worry because webpack requires "unnecessary" packages only into your server app.

You also can keep track of this issue: https://github.com/kevinbeaty/any-promise/issues/31

Comment: And ContextReplacementPlugin will remove unnecessary packages from my bundle?

Comment: @Antony ContextReplacementPlugin can remove it, but my example just suppress this warning